# Hard time to connect to my database with php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to build a homne server for studies on a raspberry pi 3.
I am just trying to connect to my raspberry database and php base to use my database on a HTML page.

I tried everything 9not apparently), to change several times my login, i tried with 'root' and create an other user and give all privileges etc, but nothing seem to work. I have all installed, **php** work just fine, i can **reach my server** with a domain name hosted by noip. the **html** and **php** content pop just fine. 
I can even connect to my database via ssh. 
But since few month i tried to make it work and i am desesperate, so if someone can help me ...

```
<?php
 $db = mysqli_connect("mywebsite","root","myLogin","mydbName")
or die(mysqli_error($db));
?>
```

so i would just be able to make request on my database, i am just blocked on that step

Comment: Provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: use`localhost` instead of `mywebsite` name. Because MySQL default server access only  localhost other wise your enabling a remote host

Comment: `mysqli_error($db)` is for query errors. You want `mysqli_connect_error()` (no arguments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$con=new mysqli("localhost","root","root_password","database_name");
```

Generally, root has no password so the connection should be like this

```
$con=new mysqli("localhost","root","","database_name");
```

Comment: this is unbelievable but by some magick i could connect to the db, sorry for the question and i cant even put an answer to the solution. i will put as resolve my question